# how can i get selected path index in group using D3 control?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

How can i change the stroke color while clicking on the path.

And also After clicking i want to maintain the same path and changed stroke color after destroying and creating the same group.

```
<g id="grproot">
    <path class="mapshape"  stroke="white" stroke-width="0.5" d="m241,9483290">
    <path class="mapshape"  stroke="white" stroke-width="0.5" d="m241,9483290">
    <path class="mapshape"  stroke="white" stroke-width="0.5" d="m241,9483290">
    <path class="mapshape"  stroke="white" stroke-width="0.5" d="m241,9483290">
    <path class="mapshape"  stroke="white" stroke-width="0.5" d="m241,9483290">
</g>
```

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this is to design a custom color scale like this:

```
var color = d3.scale.ordinal()
    .domain(["one", "two", "three"])
    .range(["#fff","#000","#333"]);
```

You would then need to assign a 'state' ie: 'one', 'two', or 'three' to each path and then color the path based on that.

When a click event happens, you would change the dataset such that the 'state' is whatever color you want it to be.  This would preserve the color throughout destroying/recreating the same group.

Hope this helps.